# Deselect a single row in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I am implementing an invert selection function where I get the selected items, select everything, and then I want to iterate over the list of selected items to deselect them.

```cpp
QModelIndexList indexs = this->selectedIndexes();
this->selectAll();
foreach(QModelIndex index, indexs)
{
   // Deselect row at index....
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the selectionModel and call `select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Deselect)` on it. You can also loop over all indices and call toggle.